# Owin provide startup class in web.config (no automatic startup discovery)

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I try to do the following in my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
   <add key="owin:appStartup" value="MyNamespace.MyStartupClass" />
</appSettings>
```

If I understand this [documentation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) correctly automatic startup detection should be disabled. So I do not require a startup attribute.

Unfortunately it looks like OWIN does not start. (I see this because I get the error: `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`. I use a controller to handle requests to the index file.)

if I use `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />` and add the startup attribute `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyStartupClass))]` then the application does startup as expected.

So the question is why? What can I do to resolve the issue?

I am using OWIN 3.0.0.0

**Update:**

This is how my startup class looks like (minified version with relevant parts):

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using MyOtherNamespace;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyOnlineStartup : MyOtherStartup
    {
        public new void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            base.Configuration(app); //Call base method! This is important because otherwise ther serilization will not be correct
            HttpConfiguration config = CreateRouting();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("exampleAppNone", "", new { controller = "MyIndex" }, null, null);
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("exampleAppIndex", "index.html", new { controller = "MyIndex" }, null, null);
            app.UseWebApi(config); // Use the WebAPI technology.
        }
    }
}
```

it derives from

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Owin;

namespace MyOtherNamespace
{
    public class MyOtherStartup
    {
        protected static HttpConfiguration CreateMyRouting()
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "myIndex",
                "my/",
                new
                {
                    controller = "MyIndex"
                },
                null,
                null
                );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "myIndex2",
                "my/index.html",
                new
                {
                    controller = "MyIndex"
                },
                null,
                null
                );
            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            return config;
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = Serialization.ClientJsonSerializer();
            serializer.ContractResolver = new MySerializationContractResolver(false);
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
            app.MapSignalR("/" + MyRequestHandler.MySignalRPath, new HubConfiguration());          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you submit `MyStartupClass` class?

Comment: What parts of my class would be relevant? It is quite big containing a lot of stuff that is unrelated. It's worth noting that my startup class is derived from another startup class residing in a class library.

Comment: Remove irrelevant parts I just want to see your class structure and outline.

Comment: And which one you registered on web.config?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simply remove this line of code in web.config file:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

Your `web.config` file now must look like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="MyNamespace.MyStartupClass" />
</appSettings>
```

By adding just `owin:appStartup` key you don't need startup attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to rename the Configure method name also..? and how to set up that in web.config  ?

Comment: @RahulUttarkar yes it is possible. Simply write your method name after the class name in the `appSetting` key's value.  i.e. `value="MyNamespace.MyStartupClass.MyMethod"`

Comment: I simply added the Microsoft.Owin.OwinStartup attribute on the namespace on my Startup class. Now, if set "owin:AutomaticAppStartup" to "false" in the web.config, then i can run from VS. However, it wont challenge/authenticate me once deployed. If i keep this line in the web.config, then it won't work when running from VS. Is this a bizarre/odd behavior?

Comment: If that line is removed, automatic startup class discovery will run! And the question specifically asks how to make it work *without* automatic startup class discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you rename your project name then also you can get this error. Please make sure to rename your assembly info & please check your project properties also. Right Click on your Project => Go To Properties => Verify your assembly name and project name.

For me this solved my issue with OWIN library.

[Project Properties Assembly Name Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZdJj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue but had to do a little more to reach a solution.

after making the changes, even restart won't solve the issue sometimes, you need to delete and add the server files to take effect.