# No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute Error

Tags: c#, web-config, owin, .net-assembly

This error

The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- The given type or method 'false' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

appears on my screen on the most face burningly ugly error page ever created in history.

[image]

Ive tried to follow the instructions on the page by inserting the owin:AutomaticAppStartup in the config.

```
 <appSettings >
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="false"></add>
        </appSettings>
```

this did not fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="false"></add>` could you try `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"></add>` and see if that works? Also, some links to help: [OWIN Startup Class Detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) and [Owin provide startup class in web.config (no automatic startup discovery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941223/owin-provide-startup-class-in-web-config-no-automatic-startup-discovery)

Comment: That did the trick. Also thanks for the resources. My Gratitude @KeyurPATEL.

Comment: I think you are missing startup.cs file

Comment: Kurkula is absolutely right. You didn't install the ASP.net auth system just to throw it away on start up. You are absolutely missing the startup.cs file at the root of the project. Put this code in the file.------------- using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(YOURPROJECT.Startup))]
namespace YOURPROJECT
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 205):

Add this code in `web.config` under the `<configuration>` tag as shown in image below. Your error should then be gone.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

[image: Check Image Below]

Comment: This is the solution, or at least this solution fixed my problem. Please mark an answer as a solution. This one should be at the top...

Comment: Thanks, This worked but can someone tell me what I'm loosing by making this setting value to false?

Answer (score 99):

I wanted to get rid of OWIN in the project:

1. Delete OWIN references and Nuget packages from project
2. Clean & Rebuild project
3. Run app

Then I got OWIN error.
These steps didn't work, **because OWIN.dll was still in bin/ directory**.

**FIX:**

1. **Delete bin/ directory manually**
2. Rebuild project

Comment: lol - deleting bin and obj folders is always the fix for weird dependency errors

Comment: I had previously downloaded and tried the SignalR nuget, which in its turn had added the owin nuget. The packages were deleted, but I also had to delete the bin folder to get it working.

Comment: Came here after installing SignalR and aborting the endeavor. Thank you.

Comment: Easy and quick. Worked for me

Comment: uninstall owin package will help as well or removing all dlls having owin with them from references will help

Comment: This solved my issue as well.  I had tried adding the web.config entry but was getting other weird errors but after trying this they all went away.

Comment: Just know that rebuild will regenerate bin folder content. solved my problem.

Comment: Another reason to AVOID dependency injection. To me, there is nothing worse than magic exceptions.

Answer (score 28):

For those who do want owin to start, `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` won't work, but the following worked for me.

1. if you have a partial class "Startup" in your Startup.Auth file, create another partial Startup class in the root of your project.
2. define an assembly owinstartup attribute pointing to that class
3. create a "Configuration" method
4. rebuild your application

You could also create the "Configuration" method, and add the assembly attribute to the Startup.Auth, but doing it this way allows you to keep your Startup class separated by leveraging C# class definition splitting. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

This is what my Startup.cs file looked like:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(ProjectNameSpace.Startup))]

namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, i realized that this happen when the project have a dot in it's name. So if the namespace its like "namespace ProjectNameSpace.ApiRest" then defining an assembly like in your example fix the problem.

Answer (score 12):

I was missing the attribute:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(projectname.Startup))]
```

Which specifies the startup class. More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Answer (score 10):

Check if you have the **Startup** class created in your project. This is an example:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof({project_name}.Startup))]

namespace AuctionPortal
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For taking advantage of ASP.net Identity. This is the solution.

Answer (score 6):

you may not have Configuration method in the class you mentioned in

```
<appSettings>
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="WebApplication1.App_Start.Startup"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because there was an extra white space in the code

**Instead of**

`<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />`

**It was**

`<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup " value="false" />`

Answer (score 3):

just replacing

```
        using (WebApp.Start(url))
```

with

```
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
```

solved my problem. The class named Startup was already implemented. as mentioned above by @robthedev

Answer (score 2):

Add the following key in Web.config will remove the code

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you have the correct startup project selected. I had a web api project as startup. That generated this error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but just in case someone is looking for the same error, try adding

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"></add>
```

after the tag `<appSettings>`

and if afterwards the next error show up:

> HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized error message

add the next code after the tag `<system.web>` it can be at the beginning

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/YourFolderName/yourFileName" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>`

In my case is:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>`

Answer (score 1):

Add class **Startup.cs** to root of project with next code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(ProjectName.Startup))]
namespace ProjectName
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug in Visual Studio 2019 V 16.10.2 that throws this error when you **have a space in your project** name whereby your namespace contains an underscore. To solve the issue, you have to explicitly set the startup class path in your web.config -> appSettings section:

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="ABC_DEF.Startup"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just deleted the `bin` and `obj` folder. Restarted the project, cleaned and build it.

Answer (score 0):

just paste this code  `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />`  in Web.config Not In web.config  there is two webconfig so be sure that it will been paste in Web.Config

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use signalr 
you haveto add **startup.cs** Class in your project

Right Click In You Project Then **Add New Item** And Select **OWIN Startup Class**

then inside **Configuration** Method Add Code Below

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

I Hope it will be useful for you

Comment: this is the real solution to the problem if you are using signalr package in your solution. than you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If deploying to Azure and you get this error. Simply delete all files on the site (backup any web.config, appsettings.json or whatver you do not want to loose) and deploy again. There are some left over dll files that should not be on the site, that makes the Azure portal think it needs to use OWIN.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your web.config file then run the project...

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs owin startup class for my case.
Add new item > OWIN Startup Class > Name Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a main site that was with Forms Authentication. I needed to create an Web Application under that site that did a Single Sign On with a Identity Provider. The SSO application had to read a cookie that are supported by Owin, and convert it to the Form cookie to make compatible both the authentications.
The problem was that it was installed under the main site the Owin Assemblies, and they, for some reason, even if they were not being used in the code or in the configuration files, were being called and trying to find the Startup class.

The solution was to uninstall all the Owin assemblies that were added by Nuget on the main site.

Answer (score 0):

My issue had a much simpler fix.

I wasn't accessing the secure site.  As soon as I pointed the browser to https://... it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied this solution from an another solution then check your namespace in your project please. Ex project namespace can be a conflict.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted all DLLs from the branch which wasn't working, then I copied all DDls from my branch which was working to my branch wich wasn't. This solved the issue.

Comment: This seems incredibly toxic. Remove and rebuild would be better.