# Optimizing start time of OWIN service on IIS (without changing to self-host)

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

Developing an OWIN service on IIS locally we noticed that start time after each build in Visual Studio is becoming slower and currently it is at **15s**. Logging shows that `Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder)`is only hit **12s** after page refresh in the browser. Which means that slowness is not due to application code but due to IIS hosting.

Running same service as self-host reduces start time to **2s** and proves that slowness is on the IIS side. The problem is, because of internal infrastructure limitations we can only host our app on IIS so unfortunately switching to self-host is not an option.

Seems like the big difference between IIS service and self-host app is an application entry point discovery. In self-host cosole app it is free because you explicitly run it in Main method:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
```

While IIS has to load and parse each dll inside bin folder in order to find `Startup` class.

This is proven indirectly with a bare minimum WebApi-app (`bin` folder is 3mb) which starts in 3s. And just by copying there all the references from slow application reduces start time to 15s.

So in order to get to `Startup` class code faster, I already tried different ways of [OWIN startup class detection](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) but it didn't help. Even the 3rd option (adding following app-setting) did not affect start time:

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupDemo.Startup, StartupDemo" />
```

So more specific question is probably: *Is there a way to make IIS discover OWIN service entry point faster, ideally as close to self-host as possible.*

**UPD**: adding the following line actually prevents you entire `OwinHttpModule` from being registered (see [PreApplicationStart.cs](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/PreApplicationStart.cs)).

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

but even custom `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod` does not get called earlier than 15s after first request.

Comment: After you did step 3, did you also do step 4 of your link and disable auto-discovery? `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup " value="false" />`

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will do what I think it does (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941223/owin-provide-startup-class-in-web-config-no-automatic-startup-discovery). Worth trying anyway, but I anticipate your app will no longer startup at all.

Comment: Thanks @RB, good point, I forgot to add this parameter. It did work with custom class name, but unfortunately start time remains the same 12s

Comment: @RB actually it doesn't work, there was just extra space in `key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup "` :)

Comment: Do you mean it *did* work (i.e. it successfully reduced startup time)? You wrote "it doesn't work"...?

Comment: @RB The start time didn't reduce with any set of parameters, what I mean by "It did work with custom class name" was the fact that the app was functioning (unlike in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941223/owin-provide-startup-class-in-web-config-no-automatic-startup-discovery). but it was only because there was a typo (extra space) in key name `"owin:AutomaticAppStartup "`. So in the end this attribute prevents OWIN module from loading exactly as in the question above.