# No owin.Environment item was found in the context. After I add Hangfire Function and added <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, startup

I recently added Hangfire to my project and added

```
 <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

to web.config , and OWIN stops working

my startup.cs looks like this

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("Inspinia_test", typeof(Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Startup))]
//[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Startup))]
namespace Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IEnumerable<IDisposable> GetHangfireServers()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseSqlServerStorage("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=HangfireTest; User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;TrustServerCertificate=true;");

            yield return new BackgroundJobServer();
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            // createRolesandUsers().Wait();

            app.UseHangfireAspNet(GetHangfireServers);
            app.UseHangfireDashboard();

            // Let's also create a sample background job
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Debug.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("myrecurringjob",() => SendMail(), Cron.Minutely);

            createRolesandUsers();
        }
```

and I have added

as suggested by the article here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

still I have the  No owin.Environment item was found in the context. issue , the problem doesnot exist before, as now I know it auto detect the the startup class before but I cannot make it work manually and any one kindly help me with this issue, thank you a lot.

I tried to add

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Inspinia_test"/>
```

to the web.config and its not working,

sorry forgot to mention

[Owin provide startup class in web.config (no automatic startup discovery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941223/owin-provide-startup-class-in-web-config-no-automatic-startup-discovery)

this seems to address the same issue, yet it remains unresolved, please help me , thank you a lot.